Where is /lib/modules/6.10.6-061006-generic/drivers in 24.04?
/lib/modules/6.10.6-061006-generic/drivers seems to be missing.  I've tried sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-generic & it says it's installed linux-headers-generic (6.8.0-45.45).
I'm trying to install the WCH9102 driver and the make fails due to this missing directory.

6.10.6-061006-generic is not a supported Ubuntu kernel, where as 6.8.0-45.45 is a supported kernel your Ubuntu system knows about. Why was a Debian or testing 6.10 kernel instlaled on your system?

Thanks for your comment. I really don't understand this. uname -r returns 6.10.6-061006-generic but I've only ever applied upgrades/updates that Ubuntu supplies. Is there a way to repair this?

The 6.10 kernel is used by Debian and not Ubuntu (24.04 LTS uses 6.8 as the GA kernel stack; and moves to 6.11 as next HWE kernel; 6.10 never got past proposed for oracular and was never deemed stable for Ubuntu). You've likely installed it yourself, and being self-installed the package system doesn't handle it (unless you added a source; but Ubuntu sources for 6.10 clearly said it was testing thus provided only 'as is'). I don't know where you installed it from, so I'd explore your apt logs, command history etc for clues or check with users with sudo rights on your box

Many thanks. Nothing in the apt logs but there's a sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-6.10.6*.deb in the history.  Looks like my son was trying to fix a python issue after the 24.04 upgrade & pulled this for some reason. I've removed it & everything seems to work properly now. Someone is going to bed early without any tea. :-)
